# Play right handed guitar upside down strung same way as a right handed guitar but I’m also right handed

Tags: chord-theory, string-instruments, lefties

I Play right handed guitar upside down strung same way as a right handed guitar but I’m right handed.

I’ve been playing this way for about 8/9 years I first played a left hand guitar left handed but just got used to playing right handed as the majority of people I knew played right handed when at parties, picking up guitars at jam sessions when I played drums for the bands etc  I love playing guitar drums also but I’ve been playing more guitar than drums lately. I still do find myself struggling to get certain riffs clean no buzzing etc

What you think of just changing back left handed guitar string lefty too and get back to the drawing board ? I sound like a clown I know but be nice to get advice maybe someone has done it before that’s all..

Thanks guy’s

Comment: Do what works for you. No-one can tell you how to do it. Most lefties play right-handed guitar. LH guitars are far more rare than LH players - either because of this… or vice versa.

Comment: So, you're right handed. Play right handed guitars, because that's what are most available. You probably play drums right handed too. Stick to what you know. As you've found, there's far more miles that way. Waste of time changing after all this time. We all have our limitations, try to push yours. The first sentence is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

A good thing about Guitars is that these were not traditionally part of the Classical Music Instrument Families but rather one that came to a good from only around the late 18th Century. These have roots from different Instruments especially the Lute just to mention.

Since Guitars weren't a part of Traditional Instrument Families, You have the freedom to choose the way you play it (Unlike Piano or Violin). Playing the Piano like a Keys player will only get people to look at you like you are a noob but thats not the case with guitars.

Getting some riffs fuzzy here and there might be a small compromise, More like playing music written for say a Violin in a Piano (I'm talking of how the Fretboard of Violin and Octaves of Piano are differently arranged, I'm not talking about Timbre here).

If you write Music yourself, Using an Upside-Down guitar might give you power at certain places. You djent with Ease in low registers for instance. But there's one con for this inverted Stringing which if you are just a Jamming/Songwriting person doesn't matter but If you are serious about music and later might even be writing for extended Music groups, Your sense of Locating Notes will be incoherent with how other instruments work. Adapting to a new instrument will be hard. It will take you longer to understand how a Violinist plays and how to write for him/her.

I guess that's all. Just one last thing. It how expressive you music is and how resilient your playing is that decides everything. Just make sure you get the point straight that you are different, not a noob.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how you play if you like the way it sounds and feels. There are traditional ways to play any instrument which are widely accepted for the tone produced, efficiency and economy of motion, etc. but ultimately it's up to the player.

If you like the tone but not the feeling, try a new way. Perhaps a left-handed guitar strung right-handed so that the body bevels and upper-neck cutaways will make more sense for your stomach and fretting hand. I'm pretty sure this is what Jimi Hendrix did.

If you like the feeling but not the tone, try different gauge strings and picks (if you use picks).

I do not recommend switching the string order or swapping hands as that will be "upside-down" in your mind and starting from scratch - why bother? Unless you hate your current way.